# Error In centos6 while compiling java classes,in tomcat6

Tags: linux, java, tomcat, centos-6

I am newbie to Linux and Centos6. I bought server just now and want to deploy my web app in it. I am getting error while I am compiling my servlet classes. It showing me bash: javac: command not found when I try to compile my classes. But when I checked my class in '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/bin .'I found my javac there. Then I checked javac with the help of command ./javac i got ERROR.. 
[root:ip_address.com]# ./javac

## There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

## pthread_getattr_np

Error occurred during initialization of VM
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
I followed the step as shown in "" Java outofmemoryerror when creating <100 threads "" which shows me command to get limits..

'[root:ipaddress.com]#  ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 278528
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited'

[root:ipaddress.com]#  top
bash: top: command not found

link :-  https://stackoverflow.com/q/12913857/1746764

Comment: After Trying Hard Day and night I solved Some Of problem And Got To know My Tomcat Configuration Is Eating My 641Mb of Memory.. How Can I change My Tomcat Config So that It eat less Memory